# Get table return value from PL/SQL stored function using JDBC

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, plsql

I have a PL/SQL stored function which returns a table of integers:

```
CREATE TYPE INT_TABLE IS TABLE OF INTEGER;

CREATE FUNCTION f (someParam IN INTEGER) RETURN INT_TABLE IS ...
```

I wish to use JDBC to retrieve the result of this function so that I can iterate through the integers in some way, be it a `ResultSet`, `int[]`, or whatever.

The function `f` performs modifications to the database, so it cannot be called in a query such as `SELECT f(42) FROM DUAL;`. The return value exists to inform the caller of the primary keys for the rows that it modified. I presumably must use a `CallableStatement`, but can't figure out exactly how. Taking inspiration from [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/jjdev/calling-PL-SQL-from-Java.html), I have tried:

```
CallableStatement cs = conn.prepareCall("{? = call f(42)}");
cs.registerOutParameter(1, Types.ARRAY);
cs.execute();
ResultSet rs = cs.getArray(1).getResultSet();
```

However, this resulted in `java.sql.SQLException: Invalid argument(s) in call` on the `registerOutParameter` line. I haven't been able to determine what this error actually means, as the docs are quite general on the exceptions that may be thrown.

I've spent hours googling and am at quite a loss as to how to proceed. Is it possible to extract a table type into Java? If not, is there some other way of returning multiple integers from the PL/SQL function that can be extracted into Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm answering my own question after figuring it out.

I was very close to the solution; I'd just missed specifying the type name in the `registerOutParameter` call. The final solution therefore looks like:

```
cs = conn.prepareCall("{? = call f(42)}");
cs.registerOutParameter(1, Types.ARRAY, "INT_TABLE");
cs.execute();
ResultSet rs = cs.getArray(1).getResultSet();
```

This is native JDBC and does not require any of the Oracle extensions.

One other thing that tripped me up was the structure of this `ResultSet`. It contains two columns; the first is the index and the second is the value ([documentation link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Array.html#getResultSet())). Therefore, if you want to extract the elements of the array, you need to call `rs.getInt(2)` for each row rather than `rs.getInt(1)`.

If one instead wanted the result as a plain array rather than a ResultSet, the corresponding type is `java.math.BigDecimal`, so it would be

```
...
cs.execute();
BigDecimal[] array = (BigDecimal[])(cs.getArray(1).getArray());
```